# Magento 1.9.2.3, Shopping Cart Rule are not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, sku

Currently I am facing issue regarding **Shopping Cart Rule** in **Magento 1.9.2.3**. I have apply rule on just Single Product SKU but somehow it applies on other product as well. Don't know whats Wrong?

[image]

Comment: I think there are no letters allowed in SKU otherwise the shopping-cart rules are not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screen you've set up a condition - a condition basically will tell Magento to check for certain items in cart (or certain checkout options like shipping address or method) - i.e. "Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products)".

However, when you want to apply a rule to a certain product you'll have to set up an action as well - i.e. "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)".

[image]

Comment: i do setup for both (Conditions & Actions), but unfortunately it applies on other product as well. Is it a bug in Magento 1.9.2.3 ???

Comment: @Crumby please add the action to your question as well